# LungoJS error on .init()

Tags: javascript, html, lungojs

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My Project</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/lungo.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/lungo.theme.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/lungo.icon.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="main">
            <article id="main-article">
                Your content
            </article>
        </section>

        <script src="assets/js/quojs/quo.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/lungo/lungo.js"></script> 
        <script>
            Lungo.init({
                name: 'My Project',
                version: '0.0.1',
                history: false
            });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Error (Chrome): http://prntscr.com/674lv0

Error (Firefox): http://prntscr.com/674pvr

Result: Screen all black

What am I doing wrong? I took this example here https://github.com/tapquo/Lungo.js/blob/master/README.md

Already tested in other browsers but all give errors.

Answer (score 1):

can you please mention the lungo version you are using?

also give a try with this version of lungo. it works for me.

http://lungo.tapquo.com/microsites/lungo/package/quo.js
http://lungo.tapquo.com/microsites/lungo/package/lungo.js